# Call to possible undefined function updateDisplayList in new class of HGroup?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:HGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            override protected function updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth : Number, unscaledHeight : Number ) : void
            {
                super.updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight );
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:HGroup>
```

- > super.updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight );
- why throwing "Call to possible undefined function updateDisplayList"  ?

Comment: i need to extend HGroup properly so all my controls inside fix their position on the resize of the group.

Comment: Erm, HGroup already does this automatically?

Comment: You are correct, but if i remove super.updateDisplayList all childs colapse at the x0 y0, like it is not HGroup. that's why i tough that overriding the updateDisplayList is mandatory.

Comment: Then don't override updateDisplayList?  I don't understand what you're trying to do by changing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark, the "s:HGroup" is no longer a DisplayObject like "HBox". Can be used just for layout and groupping. So no background color or something else can updated on HGroup.

In consequence it does not have the updateDisplayList() method inside.

I suggest to wrap your component inside a SkinableContainer and use the following "workaround" (in case you still want to stay with spark)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SkinnableContainer
          xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">
<s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            override protected function updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth : Number, unscaledHeight : Number ) : void
            {
                super.updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight );
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:HGroup>
</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

What Adrian Pirvulescu said is mostly untrue. HGroup is also a DisplayObject, and most importantly, it is also a UIComponent like its deprecated counterpart, HBox. And as such, it has the updateDisplayList method.

The warning you are receiving seems to be a bug in Flash Builder, that appears when trying to call any super protected method. Although it does not bother the actual compiler, and the application still works, it does display an annoying yellow warning in the file. I have not yet found a solution to this.